# Das Wort "die Bevorzugsliste"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Es ist mir bekannt, dass die Deutsche mögen die Worte zusammenkleben. Das finde ich selbst sehr praktisch und überhaupt nicht schwer zu lesen.

Ich übe selbst, deutsche Wörter zu finden. Manchmal bekomme ich echte Meisterwerke, manchmal völlige Dummheit. Wenn ich Wörter finde, frage ich immer Google - gibt es solche Wörter bereits?

Heute möchte ich Sie fragen, ob das Wort **die Bevorzugsliste** das Existenzrecht hat.

Google kennt [nur zwei Beispiele](https://www.google.com/search?q=Bevorzugsliste&oq=Bevorzugsliste&aqs=chrome..69i57.447j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) für die Verwendung dieses Wortes.
Das Wort möchte ich prinzipiell nicht mit der *Wunschliste* verwechseln, da die Wunschliste und die Bevorzugsliste verschiedene Dinge sein können.

Comment: Google zeigt mir auf den ersten zwei Seiten nur Vorzugsliste, wenn ich dem Link folge. "Bevorzugungsliste" wäre auch meine alternative Empfehlung.

Comment: Die spannende Frage ist: wodurch sollen sich Bevorzugsliste und Wunschliste unterscheiden? Welche Eigenschaft hat ein Ding auf der einen Liste, die es auf der anderen nicht hat?

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown *Bevorzugungsliste* klingt wie der Versuch einer Lehnübersetzung mit dem Bestandteil *preferred* (engl.), *préféré* (franz.), preferito (ital.) usw. Das Wort *bevorzugt* wird im Deutschen aber nicht in diesem Sinne gebraucht. Man spricht von *Lieblings...* oder von seinen *Favoriten*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Wort *Bevorzugsliste* ist kein korrekt [zusammengesetztes Wort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_(Grammatik)). Aus dem Sinn kann man jedoch erschließen, was gemeint ist. Richtig zusammengesetzt wären zum Beispiel

- *Vorzugsliste*

  <sup>(aus [*Vorzug*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Vorzug#1) + [Fugen-*s*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) + [*Liste*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Liste))</sup>
- *Bevorzugungsliste*

  <sup>(aus [*Bevorzugung*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Bevorzugung) + [Fugen-*s*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) + [*Liste*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Liste))</sup>
- *Bevorzugeliste*

  <sup>(aus dem Stamm von [*bevorzugen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bevorzugen) + [Fugen-*e*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) + [*Liste*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Liste))</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Aus dem Titel konnte ich den Sinn des Wortes *Bevorzugsliste* nicht erkennen. Als ich dann die Frage mit dem Hinweis auf *Wunschliste* las, gefiel mir das Wort aber sofort sehr gut.

Das Problem mit dem Verständnis liegt vermutlich darin begründet, dass die Idee hinter der Wortschöpfung wahrscheinlich aus der Komposition des Verbs *bevorzugen* und des Nomens *Liste* hervorgeht.

Komposita aus Verb und Nomen werden in der Regel gebildet, indem das Verb in der Stammform (Präsens ohne -en oder -n) mit einem Nomen gekoppelt wird. Das wäre hier also

> Bevorzug<s>en</s>liste

Das holpert aber etwas beim Sprechen, geht jedenfalls nicht so richtig flüssig über die Zunge. In solchen Fällen kann bei Verb/Nomen-Komposita ein Fugen-e eingefügt werden.

> Bevorzug**e**liste

Natürlich wäre es auch möglich, statt dessen ein Nomen zu verwenden. *Vorzug* erscheint mir aber nicht eindeutig. Es könnte dabei auch um Dinge gehen, die zeitlich *vorgezogen*, also früher als andere Dinge erledigt werden müssen. *Bevorzugung* wäre möglich und man bräuchte dann wieder einen Fugenlaut, um nicht über die eigene Zunge zu stolpern.

> Bevorzugung**s**liste

Das klingt in meinen Ohren aber sehr formal und hat für mein Sprachgefühl sogar einen leicht negativen Beigeschmack, ohne dass ich spontan sagen könnte, woher das kommt. Auf jeden Fall nimmt es in meinen Augen der Wortschöpfung den Charme. Mein Favorit ist daher eindeutig

> Bevorzugeliste.

Für mehr Informationen zu Komposita scheint mir https://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache-lernen.de/deutsche-substantive-zusammengesetzte-nomen-komposita/ eine recht angenehme Quelle zu sein.

Comment: Vielen Dank für solche tolle Erklärung!